# Real time data graphing on a line chart with the help of rickshaw and d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, d3.js

I want to make real time dynamic graph on line chart with the help of rickshaw and d3.js,  which always gives fresh data without refreshing the whole page. In the following example they build the graph on random data. But in this problem data is not fresh only refreshing of browser will get fresh data [Please see this link](http://code.runnable.com/UlbPx4tJHRIWAABB/rickshaw-examples-graph-with-interactive-hover-details). For ajax request I am using reference from here [please see it](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/examples/ajax.html)

I copied the whole code below. I want to make graph which is movable, like real time update some like [flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/), But don't want to use flot, but rickshaw.

```html
    <!doctype>
<head>
        <title>rickShaw greaph examples</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../src/css/graph.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../src/css/legend.css">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../src/css/detail.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/lines.css">

    <script src="../vendor/d3.v3.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../rickshaw.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="chart_container" style="margin:0px auto;width:660px;">
    <div id="chart"></div>
        <div id="legend_container">
            <div id="smoother" title="Smoothing"></div>
            <div id="legend"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="slider"></div>
</div>

<script>
       // set up our data series with 50 random data points
        var seriesData = [ [], [], [] ];
        var random = new Rickshaw.Fixtures.RandomData(150);

        for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
            random.addData(seriesData);
        }

var ajaxGraph = new Rickshaw.Graph.Ajax( {

    element: document.getElementById("chart"),
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    renderer: 'line',
    series: [
        {
            name: 'New York',
                        data: seriesData[0],
            color: '#c05020',
        }, {
            name: 'London',
                        data: seriesData[0],
            color: '#30c020',
        }, {
            name: 'Tokyo',
                        data: seriesData[0],
            color: '#6060c0'
        }
    ]
} );
ajaxGraph.render();

var hoverDetail = new Rickshaw.Graph.HoverDetail( {
            graph: graph
        } );

        var legend = new Rickshaw.Graph.Legend( {
            graph: graph,
            element: document.getElementById('legend')

        } );

        var shelving = new Rickshaw.Graph.Behavior.Series.Toggle( {
            graph: graph,
            legend: legend
        } );

       
        var axes = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Time( {
            graph: graph
        } );
        axes.render();
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get realtime data in a d3 chart, you will need to either implement a polling script on the JSON URL or utilize websockets for real-time communication.

A polling script would query the JSON URL every X seconds, and execute the d3 add / update / delete pattern as appropriate.

With websockets, you can maintain a persistant connection to the API and the server sends messages to connected clients when the data is updated. This again would call the d3 add / update / delete pattern.

SO example with web sockets:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13694422/2490989

Polling example:

http://www.devixgroup.com/blog/2015/01/using-ajax-polling-with-d3-js-eventdrops-project/

Comment: I have used both methods, but unfortunately they were proprietary prototypes for major companies :/    websocket example on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672490/real-time-data-with-d3 and a polling example: http://www.devixgroup.com/blog/2015/01/using-ajax-polling-with-d3-js-eventdrops-project/